# Upgrading to Dart2 gives me silent errors

Tags: dart, dart-2

I have a fairly involved 1.0 dart app I'm trying to upgrade along with another programmer, and we keep being stumped by silent errors.

Just in time compilations fail with no information other than just "Build Failed".  Running build_runner in verbose mode shows that there is an AssetNotFoundException in dartdevc.module itself, but no actaul useful errors (such as what asset in particular can't be found).

Is there any way I can get actually useful information out of this?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.dartlang.org/dart-2#migration and see if any of that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the build with `--verbose` to get more details and a stack trace. If there are cases with error messages that are not effectively pointing to the problem you can file an issue at https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues - ideally with a reproduction case. If your project is open source and we can access the repo we should be able to use it as a reproduction case to check.